# Jquery: input type=submit still submits even when disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a submit button that I am trying to disable programmatically but for some reason, when I change the disabled attribute of the element, I can still click submit and the event code still fires.

As an example, I have the following element in my html:

```
<input name="reg_submit" id="reg_button" value="Buddy" class="reg_button reg_button_new crm_submit" type="submit">
```

and have the following in my script to disable it:

```
var k = jQuery.noConflict();
k('#reg_button').attr("disabled", true);
```

And when I print debug, the element is in fact disabled. Is my approach flawed?

Comment: What is `k` in `k("#reg_button")`?

Comment: try `$('#reg_button').prop("disabled", true);`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the disabled property.

```js
var k = jQuery.noConflict();
k('#reg_button').prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="reg_submit" id="reg_button" value="Buddy" class="reg_button reg_button_new crm_submit" type="submit">
```